# Initialize multiple instances of classes that implements same interface in spring xml

Tags: java, spring

I have two classes implementing an interface. The classes are in two different packages.

```
package com.service;
public interface PServices{ }

package com.transaction.service.v2;
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class PServicesImpl implements PServices {}


package com.transaction.service.v1;
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class PServicesImpl implements PServices {}
```

I initialize the classes in the spring xml as follows:

```
<bean id="pServicesv1"
    class="com.transaction.service.v1.PServicesImpl" />

    <bean id="pServicesv2"
    class="com.transaction.service.v2.PServicesImpl" />
```

But during server startup i am getting the following error.

> No unique bean of type com.service.PServices is defined: expected
>   single bean but found 2

How to initialize multiple classes here? I cannot use annotations due to restrictions..

Answer (score 1):

During server start you get the error because you are trying to Inject/Autowire the Interface and not the actual implementation. When you try to Inject/Autowire Spring will try to identify which bean to Inject/Autowire. Since you have two defined beans of the same type (Interface), Spring couldn't determine which one to Inject.

Use `autowire="byName"` in the bean definition so that when you try to Inject/Autowire the interface, it will inject the bean based on the name.

```
 <bean id="pServicesv1"
    class="com.transaction.service.v1.PServicesImpl" 
    autowire="byName"/>
```